# Criteria API select distinct date using postgres date function

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, criteria-api

I have the following postgres query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT DATE(created_date) as day FROM registrations GROUP BY created_date ORDER BY DATE(created_date) ASC
```

I am attempting to convert this to the criteria api and use it with a specification predicate. The `registration.createdDate` is of `LocalDateTime` on the entity. The column in postgres is of type `timestamp with timezone`

```
var builder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();

var dateCriteriaQuery = builder.createQuery(Date.class);
Root<Registration> root = dateCriteriaQuery.from(Registration.class);

dateCriteriaQuery.select(builder.function("DATE", Date.class, root.get(Registration_.createdDate)).as(Date.class).alias("date"));

GenericSpecificationsBuilder<Registration> specificationsBuilder = new GenericSpecificationsBuilder<>();
Specification<Registration> specification = specificationsBuilder.buildSpecificationFromSearchOperationRequest(searchOperationRequest, RegistrationSpecification::new);
Predicate predicate = specification.toPredicate(root, dateCriteriaQuery, builder);
dateCriteriaQuery.where(predicate);

TypedQuery<Date> typedQuery = entityManager.createQuery(dateCriteriaQuery);
return typedQuery.getResultList();
```

The following error is occuring

```
org.hibernate.QueryException: No data type for node: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.MethodNode 
 \-[METHOD_CALL] MethodNode: 'function (DATE)'
    +-[METHOD_NAME] IdentNode: 'DATE' {originalText=DATE}
    \-[EXPR_LIST] SqlNode: 'exprList'
       \-[DOT] DotNode: 'registrati0_.created_date' {propertyName=createdDate,dereferenceType=PRIMITIVE,getPropertyPath=createdDate,path=generatedAlias0.createdDate,tableAlias=registrati0_,className=com.entity.Registration,classAlias=generatedAlias0}
          +-[ALIAS_REF] IdentNode: 'registrati0_.id' {alias=generatedAlias0, className=com.entity.Registration, tableAlias=registrati0_}
          \-[IDENT] IdentNode: 'createdDate' {originalText=createdDate}
 [select distinct function('DATE', generatedAlias0.createdDate) from com.entity.Registration as generatedAlias0 where generatedAlias0.id>1L]
```

How can I select the distinct dates using the postgres date function?